# Add zero padding to numbers in a column by using str_pad in string package in r

Tags: r, string

I want to use the `string str_pad` function to make a column in my desired format, which includes zero padding the numbers in the "Code" column to 3 digits.

I've run this code:

```
Animals %>%
gather(most_common, cnt, M:OG) %>% 
group_by(name) %>% 
slice(which.max(cnt)) %>%
arrange(code)
```

Which resulted in the following tibble:

```
Code      Name       most_common
32       Monkey        Africa
33       Wolf          Europe
34       Tiger         Asia
35       Godzilla      Asia
#With 1 234 more rows
```

I'm happy with my code above. **However, because I'm going to merge this df later on, I need the "Code" column to be three digits with zero padding (i.e. in the format "nnn" / "032"), as this:**

```
Code      Name       most_common
032       Monkey        Africa
033       Wolf          Europe
034       Tiger         Asia
035       Godzilla      Asia
#With 1 234 more rows
```

I've run `string str_pad($code, $3, $0)`, but it doesn't work. I guess there's something wrong there. Should I run this code wherever I want in my chunk or by using `%>%`?

Comment: `str_pad(df$Code, 3, "left", 0)`

Comment: `str_pad` takes a vector as input. In `dplyr`, if you want to modify a column in place (treating it as a vector), we use `mutate`. So `... %>% mutate(Code = str_pad(Code, width = 3, side = "left", pad = "0"))`.